# Getting the WebHostHttpRequestContext in a custom filter for Web API Asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api

I'm currently trying to write a custom filter in my Web API that will allow me to update our database when a user makes a request per their LastActivity time stamp. To do this I need to access their username which is available in the WebHostHttpRequestContext and is viewable when I debug and go down a few layers, but I can't seem to figure out how to access it with my code.

Any idea how I can access this object and get values from it? Here is what I'm working with so far,

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Http.Filters;
using MyWebAPI.Models.DAL;

namespace MyWebAPI.App_Service
{
    public class MyActionFilter : System.Web.Http.Filters.ActionFilterAttribute
    {
        public override void OnActionExecuted(HttpActionExecutedContext actionExecutedContext)
        {

            var principal = actionExecutedContext.Response.Content;

            //using (var db = new databaseContext())
            //{
            //    var dbUser = (from b in db.AspNetUsers
            //                  where b.UserName == principal.Identity.Name
            //                  select b).First();

            //    dbUser.LastActivity = DateTime.Now;
            //    db.SaveChanges();
            //}
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If what you are after is the principal. Try accessing it via the `HttpActionExecutedContext.ActionContext.RequestContext.Principal`. It should be populated provided the request has be authenticated and a user principal was assign to the request.

```
namespace MyWebAPI.App_Service {
    public class MyActionFilter : System.Web.Http.Filters.ActionFilterAttribute {
        public override void OnActionExecuted(System.Web.Http.Filters.HttpActionExecutedContext actionExecutedContext) {

            var principal = actionExecutedContext.ActionContext.RequestContext.Principal;
            if(principal != null) {
                using (var db = new databaseContext()) {
                    var dbUser = (from b in db.AspNetUsers
                                where b.UserName == principal.Identity.Name
                                select b).First();

                    dbUser.LastActivity = DateTime.Now;
                    db.SaveChanges();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is great thank you, I don't have a chance to try it right now but will tomorrow but this feels like exactly what I've been looking for today thank!

Answer (score 1):

Although the class is internal, you can treat the WebHostHttpContext object as a dynamic and get it from actionExecutedContext.Request.Properties["MS_RequestContext"].

The following code worked when I needed the original HttpRequestWrapper from my request context (to get POST body data) for example.

```
 dynamic requestContext = actionContext.Request.Properties["MS_RequestContext"];
 var requestWrapper = (HttpRequestWrapper)requestContext.Context.Request;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
// Cast to  (actionContext.RequestContext as WebHostHttpRequestContext).Context
var context = actionContext.RequestContext
                .GetType().Assembly.GetType("System.Web.Http.WebHost.WebHostHttpRequestContext")
                .GetProperty("Context")
                ?.GetMethod
                .Invoke(actionContext.RequestContext, null) as HttpContextWrapper;
var request = context?.Request;
```